# Good OleDB/ODBC provider for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, oledb

I'm in need of a functional OleDB data provider for PostgreSQL. It should be similar to the ODBC provider for MySQL. See http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/5.1.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The postgres [software catalog](http://www.postgresql.org/download/products/2) has some providers on there.

Comment: What makes most of these "connectors" cost? Why would I ever use one over the standard?

Answer (score 1):

dotConnect for PostgreSQL (from Devart) offers a pretty good one.  It is fast and works.  The free version will give you your basic ADO.net support, the pay offers everything else.  ODBC doesn't have a free version. 
http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/   
**edit** 
Adding the direct link to the ODBC connector as it is on a separate page. 
https://www.devart.com/odbc/postgresql/

Comment: I guess some one did not like the devart tool and down voted my answer.  But the answer isn't any less correct.  This site isn't an editorial on your religious feelings on open source vs proprietary code. Its about answering the questions.

Comment: dotConnect for PostgreSQL does not appear to include an OLEDB nor ODBC driver.  It is a native library for accessing PostgreSQL.

Comment: I answered this a long time ago.  It used to be all in one section.  It has been split up.  You just have to navigate to the other part of the website.  They do have a ODBC connector too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the last version of ODBC for PosgreSQL :
http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/

Enter in the "msi" folder for the installer.
But be careful, when you are using ODBC, there is a 32bits and a 64bits version. So choose the right one.