# .NET connector for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Last time I used Npgsql, i.e., version 1.0, it worked very slow. Is there any other alternative to Npgsql?

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332518/good-oledb-odbc-provider-for-postgresql

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Version 1.0 is three years old. Try to use [the newest one](http://pgfoundry.org/frs/?group_id=1000140&release_id=1628).

Comment: It depends on what do you mean by "fast". I used it when I was working with Postgre DB and I didn't have any performance problems. I doubt that there is better .NET connector for Postgre than Npgsql.

Comment: It's as fast as the queries you make , and how your tables are optimized to fit your queries. npgsql adds no significant overhead.

Comment: Latest version takes 5 seconds to connection.Open() for me every 5 requests. PsPing hits the db in 10ms, queries are 10ms. Not sure what to do.

Answer (score 4):

Npgsql is an excellent connector.  Just upgrade to the new one.  Make sure you take a look at the documentation it is really good. That will solve the speed issue.

You asked about an alternative, so I also have to recommend an another good connector: dotConnect for PostgreSQL.  It is made by Devart.  There is a simple free one as well as a fully robust pay connector.  The pay one has Linq and entity framework support.
http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/

Answer (score 1):

I have experience with the .NET MySQL connector. What you are describing seems to be a DNS issue. If you are using a URL in your connection string and are able to change it to an IP address, try that and see if your delay goes away.

Comment: It was a connection pool issue. It was dropping connections from the pool after 1-2 seconds when a minimum connection size was not set. Nonetheless, I am interested in alternatives. I tried a few out and there was no documentation / it did not work as described. Npqsql seems to be the main one.

Answer (score 1):

**npgsql** is still the choice for .NET when connecting to PostgreSQL.

Since version 1.0, the connector has improved drastically, check out [this presentation](https://slides.com/shayrojansky/dotnetos-2018-11-05#/) from [Shay Rojansky](https://twitter.com/shayrojansky); it is not the latest, still the boost was already quite impressive in 2018/11.

If you are upgrading from an old version, read the release [notes of the latest](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/release-notes/3.0.html) carefully, you might break functionality in your code.

Also, I strongly recommend considering [optimizing PostgreSQL](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Performance_Optimization) as well. I work with it daily in a distributed enterprise environment, with massive workloads; it can be tuned and tweaked with a dramatic impact on the overall performance.

Answer (score 0):

1. As @yojimbo87 told upgrade  to newer connector version. Try that.
2. Use entity core framework. Npgsql has an Entity Framework (EF) Core provider.
3. Use Postgres 11
4. Check connection pool setting
   Like most ADO.NET providers, Npgsql uses connection pooling by default. When you Close() the NpgsqlConnection object, an internal object representing the actual underlying connection that Npgsql uses goes into a pool to be re-used, saving the overhead of creating another unnecessarily.

This suits most applications well, as it's common to want to use a connection several times in the space of a second.

It doesn't suit you at all, but if you include the option Pooling=false in your connection string, it will override this default, and Close() will indeed close the actual connection.

Npgsql has an Entity Framework (EF) Core provider. It behaves like other EF Core providers (e.g. SQL Server), so the general EF Core docs apply here as well. If you're just getting started with EF Core, those docs are the best place to start.

Development happens in the Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL repository, all issues should be reported there.
https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/index.html